# jQuery - modify the prompt/alert functions

Tags: jquery, alert, prompt

I need an advice, if it's worth it to downlaod a jQuery plugin ([such as Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)), or if it's easier to make my own code just to modify the "prompt" efect. All I need is something like the first example of [THIS](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php).

Or is there any other way, how to show a box of text in the midle of the screen, that stays there even when I move scroll and to fade the background a bit, while the box is shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Impromptu has the function you need, why reinvent the wheels?

If you just need a box to show text and be able to do non-modal(ie, just overlay and you can still have the others functional, jqueryUI dialog surely does.

Comment: Because I'd like to know how to make such a thing myself. I just haven't found any tutorial on that thing, so I'm not sure if it's not too hard ... :-/

Comment: Impromptu is about 300 lines of fairly dense code.  So I guess you'll have to decide which is more important...getting your application running or learning a new skill.  To do it properly you will need to know JQuery, Javascript, and CSS styling.